# Excel VBA - How to stop Find Function when criteria met

Tags: vba, excel, find

I'm using this line of code in a loop:

```
Set foundCell = Cells.Find(What:=pasteValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

It's working perfectly but it is very slow due to the size of the document.
The "Find" function keeps on searching until the EOF even if the criteria is met at the 1st row, and I'm running it on a reeeeeally large sheet. Is there a way to stop Find function at the first met criteria?

Thanks!

Edit:

```
Sub Finding()

Dim foundCell As Range
Dim pasteValue As String
Dim MyDataObj As MSForms.DataObject

Set MyDataObj = New MSForms.DataObject

Windows("Book3").Activate
Selection.Copy
Windows("Book1").Activate

MyDataObj.GetFromClipboard
pasteValue = MyDataObj.GetText(1)
pasteValue = Trim(Replace(pasteValue, Chr(13) & Chr(10), ""))

Do Until IsEmpty(pasteValue) Or pasteValue = ""

    Set foundCell = Cells.Find(What:=pasteValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        Windows("Book3").Activate
        Selection.Offset(0, 4).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "Y"
        Selection.Offset(1, -4).Select
    End If

    Windows("Book3").Activate
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book1").Activate

    MyDataObj.GetFromClipboard
    pasteValue = MyDataObj.GetText(1)
    pasteValue = Trim(Replace(pasteValue, Chr(13) & Chr(10), ""))

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: can you restrict the range you are searching? It looks like you are searching all cells in the active worksheet... Normally it might not matter...but perhaps it does in your case.

Comment: Let me paste the whole code to show better my question:

Comment: I can't restrict the range.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running find function in a with or for loop, then you can exit sub if your result is not empty. If you want macro to run from another specific point then you can use goto ->

```
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    exit sub
```

or

```
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    GoTo LineNumber or Identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not really clear to me but add `Exit Do` where you want to stop the loop. if I understand right this should be in the `If` statement after matching the search and delete the row:

```
 If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
        Windows("Book3").Activate
        Selection.Offset(0, 4).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "Y"
        Selection.Offset(1, -4).Select
        Exit Do 'Exit the loop
    End If
```

Comment: I don't want to stop the loop.

There are about 30000 rows. At Excel, it takes about 2s to perform the FIND function, even if the value was found in the 1st searched row.